# Пунктуация в ССП

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

> В саду горит костер, и крепко тянет душистым дымом вишневых сучьев

Почему тут нужна запятая, если есть общий второстепенный член *"в саду"*? (предложение из школьного диктанта)

Comment: В чем могу согласться с вашим недоумением, так это в том, что если это диктант (как вы уверяете в комментариях к ответу grizzly), то крайне нелогично требовать расстановки знаков в соответствии с контекстом, которого там нет, во фразе, которую не писал автор. Поэтому запятая вполне может быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) А вот и оригинальный текст.

*К ночи в погоду становится очень холодно и росисто. Надышавшись на гумне ржаным ароматом новой соломы и мякины, **бодро идешь домой к ужину мимо садового вала.** Голоса на деревне или скрип ворот раздаются по студеной заре необыкновенно ясно. Темнеет. **И вот еще запах: в саду – костер, и крепко тянет душистым дымом вишневых сучьев.***

Действительно, когда идешь мимо садового вала, то дымом тянет не в саду, а из сада. Так что в авторском тексте нет общего второстепенного члена.

Из словаря Ожегова: **ТЯНУТЬ** 10. безл., **чем. О струе воздуха, запахе: распространяться.** Тянет холодом из окна. Тянет дымом.

В нашем случае: **тянет дымом из сада,** а наблюдатель проходит мимо.

2) Но составителей диктантов детали мало волнуют, с **классикой они обращаются совершенно свободно**.

По авторскому тексту можно можно составить предложение без запятой, но при этом лучше заменить глагол  "тянуть": *В саду горит костер и крепко **пахнет** душистым дымом вишневых сучьев.*

Всё это происходит в саду, поэтому это общий член.

Comment: Sharon, а как бы вы объяснили запятую в авторской версии? Ведь тут на первый взгляд имеет место однородность поясняемых "в саду костер" и "крепко тянет..." при общей поясняемой конструкции. Тут отсылками, что не из того места пахнет, не отделаться. Хорошо бы это в тексте ответа обозначить...

Comment: Семантика важна, даже из контекста. В авторской версии стоит тире, там  без запятой уж точно не обойтись (ни по структуре, ни по интонации). Если бы не было тире, то, возможно, автор написал бы так: И вот еще запах: в саду горит костер, и оттуда крепко тянет душистым дымом. Остается только догадываться. Вот поэтому классику надо переделывать осторожно.

Comment: Да Бог с ним, с контекстом. Правило объясните, пожалуйства, если можете, по которому запятая сохраняется вопреки общей логике. Нужен контекст - привлекайте, но именно как контекст, а не как замену правила.

Comment: Пожалуйста, только без авторского тире: "И вот еще запах: в саду горит костер и крепко  пахнет (тянет) душистым дымом вишневых сучьев". Но только вы тогда находитесь в саду и рассказываете, чем там пахнет, а не проходите мимо. Семантику глагола "тянуть" тоже не учитываем. Тогда всё логично и по правилам.

Comment: Я хочу увидеть это правило. Или ссылку на него. И vice-versa:  правило, которое ставит  контекст условием наличия запятой при однородных пояснительных в БСС.

Comment: Я только по Розенталю работаю. 3) Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями ССП третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.); Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль (Купр.); Но: Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла, небо прояснилось, и мы отправились (П.) — последняя часть не входит в разъяснение.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  Как мы видим, семантика текста/контекста оказывает влияние на решение.

Answer (score 1):

А Вы читали Бунина? Дымом там тянет не в саду, а когда проходишь мимо. И, вообще говоря, *тянет дымом* обычно не в том месте, где горит, а где-то рядом. Поэтому можно сделать вывод, что это ССП с причинно-следственными отношениями: костёр горит, поэтому тянет дымом. Обычно считается (в теории), что причинно-следственные отношения в ССП с союзом **и** не выражаются формально, а определяются контекстом. Но в целом теория причинно-следственных отношений в таких ССП не такая уж простая и вряд ли полностью изучена.

Comment: В диктанте это предложение было, за оригинальный текст не ручаюсь.

Comment: @АнтонШестаков С предложением всё нормально, хотя это и не точная цитата. Просто в контексте явно сказано, что запах слышно, когда проходишь мимо. Я немного углубил свой ответ отсылкой к теории. (Если это студенческий диктант, то такую теорию должны были уже изучать, а если школьный — тогда у меня нет слов.)

Comment: Школьный. Учитель говорил, что запятая стоит из-за смысловых отношений причины, но такого правила я не нашел, поэтому тут решил спросить)

Answer (score 1):

При наличии общего члена в предложении запятая не ставится в том случае, если, как говорится, одно не вытекает из другого. Например: В саду горел костер и дети пели песни.
Дети пели не потому, что горел костер. Запятая не ставится.
В нашем же случае тянуло дымом, потому что горел костер. Второе действие зависит от первого. Запятая ставится

Comment: Вы считаете, что при наличии общего члена ставится запятая, "если, как говорится, одно вытекает из другого"? Вы могли бы дать ссылку на это правило? А то ведь у Розенталя и правила другие, и примеры к ним противоречат Вашему правилу.